# Pandas causing EXE file (Using PyInstaller) to have an enormous size (almost 0.5 GB)

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have a program with a single line of code

```
import pandas
```

I converted this to exe file using PyInstaller...and the final size of the output is 376MB!! This is an enormous size...how come a single line would consume almost 0.5GB of data?

I know that probably this is because the whole library of pandas has to be converted to EXE so I was wondering if there's a way to only include the parts of Pandas that are relevant? or is there an alternative library to Pandas that is much smaller?

I had an option of developing the program using VBA or Python but when converting to EXE I really regret it. I can't tell my customer that my program is that large for such a simple task.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try only importing the parts you need. (P.S. I don’t have experience in pandas but I think this will work.) Like doing: from pandas import some_library

Comment: Use `pyi-archive-viewer` to identify the large components of your app.

Comment: My wild guess is that Pandas requires `numpy`, `matplotlib` which require other stuff. `numpy` alone can be huge as it could include the C backend, `matplotlib` might include other rendering backend as well...

Comment: Also, pyinstaller isn’t compiling the program or anything, it’s just merely packing the program, the libraries, AND the python runtime environment into a single exe, just in case if you didn’t know.